# error install phpmyadmin for ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, installation, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I run command: sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin to install phpMyAdmin.
then i receive result 
Err http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe phpmyadmin all 4:3.4.11.1-1
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_3.4.11.1-1_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
i try update command apt-get  more than once update then run command sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin but i receive error

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the PPA from here
https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/phpmyadmin

Its much more recent/updated than the main line phpmyadmin from the official repos